# super.__init__() either complains about too many positional arguments or KeyErrors

Tags: python, initialization, init, fmi

I'm trying to generate an FMU using pythonfmu, but I'm having problems with my **init**(). I've also added the main code, where the the class FmuGenerator gets initialized:

My Application opens a gui where I can enter the address of an OPC UA Server. After pushing the “connect” Button, my opcua_client.py gets the nodes of the server. Those get displayed in the gui. There, I can then select the nodes I want to integrate in my FMU. So far, all of this is working. Now I want to generate the FMU with my selected_nodes. But that's where the error occurs.

This is the code:

```
from pythonfmu import FmuBuilder, Fmi2Causality,Fmi2Variability, Fmi2Slave, Boolean, Integer, Real, String, Fmi2Initial
import subprocess
#    - Unabhängige Klasse, die für die Generierung des FMU-Objekts aus den ausgewählten Nodes verantwortlich ist.
#    - Nutzt `pythonfmu` zur Erstellung des FMU-Objekts.

class FmuGenerator(Fmi2Slave):
    input_nodes=[]
    author = "Till"
    description = "A Test FMU"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        
        for node in self.input_nodes:
            display_text=(node)
            print(display_text)
        
        # Füge die Eingänge zum FMU hinzu
            self.register_variable(Integer(f"{node}",variability=Fmi2Variability.continuous,causality=Fmi2Causality.input, start=0.0))

        subprocess.run("pythonfmu build -f fmu_generator.py VSCode", shell=True)
    
    def generate_fmu(self, selected_nodes):
        # Code zur Erzeugung des FMU-Objekts
        #print(selected_nodes)
        self.input_nodes=selected_nodes
        #super().__init__()
        
        
        # for node in self.input_nodes:
        #     display_text=(node)
        #     print(display_text)
        
        # # Füge die Eingänge zum FMU hinzu
        #     self.register_variable(Integer(f"{node}",variability=Fmi2Variability.continuous,causality=Fmi2Causality.input, start=0.0))
        # #self.register_variable(Integer("input_2",variability=Fmi2Variability.continuous,causality=Fmi2Causality.input, start=0.0))
      
        self.__init__()
        # python command mit build?!
        pass

    def do_step(self, current_time, step_size):
        
        return True
#### this is the main Application:

from gui_manager import GUIManager
from node_manager import NodeManager
from fmu_generator import FmuGenerator

#    - Diese Klasse ist der Haupt-Controller der Anwendung. 
#    - Sie initialisiert die GUI und verwaltet den gesamten Workflow, einschließlich der Erstellung des FMU.
 

class Application:
    def __init__(self):

        self.gui_manager = GUIManager(self)
        self.node_manager = NodeManager()
        #self.fmu_generator = FmuGenerator()

    def start(self):
        self.gui_manager.show()

    def on_server_address_entered(self, address):
        nodes_list= self.node_manager.connect_and_retrieve_nodes(address)
        self.gui_manager.display_nodes(nodes_list)

    def on_nodes_selected(self, selected_nodes):
        self.fmu_generator = FmuGenerator()
        self.fmu_generator.generate_fmu(selected_nodes)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Application()
    app.start()
```

Which returns the following Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tbro03\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\tbro03\OneDrive - Staubli\Documents\Abschlussarbeit\VSCode\gui_manager.py", line 94, in select_nodes
    self.application.on_nodes_selected(self.selcted_nodes)
  File "c:\Users\tbro03\OneDrive - Staubli\Documents\Abschlussarbeit\VSCode\application.py", line 24, in on_nodes_selected
    self.fmu_generator = FmuGenerator(self)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\tbro03\OneDrive - Staubli\Documents\Abschlussarbeit\VSCode\fmu_generator.py", line 12, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
TypeError: Fmi2Slave.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

If I change it like this:

```
from pythonfmu import FmuBuilder, Fmi2Causality,Fmi2Variability, Fmi2Slave, Boolean, Integer, Real, String, Fmi2Initial
import subprocess
#    - Unabhängige Klasse, die für die Generierung des FMU-Objekts aus den ausgewählten Nodes verantwortlich ist.
#    - Nutzt `pythonfmu` zur Erstellung des FMU-Objekts.

class FmuGenerator(Fmi2Slave):
    input_nodes=[]
    author = "Till"
    description = "A Test FMU"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        
        for node in self.input_nodes:
            display_text=(node)
            print(display_text)
        
        # Füge die Eingänge zum FMU hinzu
            self.register_variable(Integer(f"{node}",variability=Fmi2Variability.continuous,causality=Fmi2Causality.input, start=0.0))

        subprocess.run("pythonfmu build -f fmu_generator.py VSCode", shell=True)
    
    def generate_fmu(self, selected_nodes):
        # Code zur Erzeugung des FMU-Objekts
        #print(selected_nodes)
        self.input_nodes=selected_nodes
        #super().__init__()
        
        
        # for node in self.input_nodes:
        #     display_text=(node)
        #     print(display_text)
        
        # # Füge die Eingänge zum FMU hinzu
        #     self.register_variable(Integer(f"{node}",variability=Fmi2Variability.continuous,causality=Fmi2Causality.input, start=0.0))
        # #self.register_variable(Integer("input_2",variability=Fmi2Variability.continuous,causality=Fmi2Causality.input, start=0.0))
      
        self.__init__()
        # python command mit build?!
        pass

    def do_step(self, current_time, step_size):
        
        return True
```

This returns the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tbro03\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\tbro03\OneDrive - Staubli\Documents\Abschlussarbeit\VSCode\gui_manager.py", line 94, in select_nodes
    self.application.on_nodes_selected(self.selcted_nodes)
  File "c:\Users\tbro03\OneDrive - Staubli\Documents\Abschlussarbeit\VSCode\application.py", line 24, in on_nodes_selected
    self.fmu_generator = FmuGenerator(self)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\tbro03\OneDrive - Staubli\Documents\Abschlussarbeit\VSCode\fmu_generator.py", line 12, in __init__
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\tbro03\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pythonfmu\fmi2slave.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.instance_name = kwargs["instance_name"]
                         ~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'instance_name'
```

I also tried `__init__(instance_name=FmuGenerator)`, didnt help either.
If someone knows what to do please let me know.

Comment: it shows problem in `self.fmu_generator = FmuGenerator(self)` but I don't see it in your code. Error may suggest that it doesn't allow for arguments - so maybe remove `self` from  `FmuGenerator()` and do `self.fmu_generator = FmuGenerator()`

Comment: maybe you should check documentation for `Fmi2Slave` because it seems its `__init__` doesn't allow to get values. And it may need `super().__init__()` without `*args` and without `**kwargs`

Comment: `Fmi2Slave.__init__` takes only keyword arguments (other than self) See [the source code](https://github.com/NTNU-IHB/PythonFMU/blob/c63e614636f09e03728d83f2c1178b4fc789019b/pythonfmu/fmi2slave.py#L41)

Comment: @furas I did that, but still get this KeyError

Comment: @buran ok, but what do i have to give her then ?

Comment: Don't accept and don't pass `*args`. It's even in the [example](https://pypi.org/project/pythonfmu/)

Comment: If I do:
```   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        ``` 
I still get the KeyError

Comment: Do you pass `instance_name` argument? No, you don't - `self.fmu_generator = FmuGenerator(self)`

Comment: Well I tried that too, doesnt help either

Comment: better show `minimal working code` in question - so we could simply copy and test it on our computers.

Comment: @furas what do you mean by `minimal working code` ?

Comment: short code with your problem - which we could simply copy and run on our computers.

Comment: you can also read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example - Help Center - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @furas I've added the main code, where FMUGenerator() gets initialized. Does that help? Because i dont know how i can shorten the example code. I've got like 5 diffrent scripts, which together build the complete Application.

Comment: Note that example shows the workflow, e.g. `pythonfmu build -f myscript.py requirements.txt` not sure what your `gui_manager.py` and `application.py` are

Comment: So my Application opens a gui where I can enter the address of an OPC UA Server. After pushing the “connect” Button, my `opcua_client.py` gets the nodes of the server. Those get displayed in the gui. There, I can then select the nodes I want to integrate in my FMU. So far, all of this is working. Now I want to generate the FMU with my `selected_nodes`. But that's where the error occurs.

Comment: @furas @buran any idea what he wants as `instance_name`?

Comment: maybe problem is in different place - you have `self.__init__()` (without `instance_name`) in `generate_fmu()` and it can make problem with `KeyError` but I don't know why you use it. If you want to run again code from `__init__` then put it in separated `method` and later use this method first time in `__init__` and later run it in other function instead of `__init__`

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: Maybe you have two similar problem in different places in code: (1) when you create `FmuGenerator` with too many arguments, (2) when you use `self.__init__()` without arguments. And you have to read details in error message. Last error shows problem in `line 24, in on_nodes_selected` but I don't see `on_nodes_selected` in your code.

Comment: @furas in the upper code section, in the class Application there is the method `on_nodes_selected`. How  am I supposed to initiate the class ?

Comment: maybe you have few mistakes in different places and when you fix one problem then you see other error and it may look like previous fix didn't help - so you have to read error messages carefully.

Comment: Maybe see [repo on GitHub](https://github.com/NTNU-IHB/PythonFMU/tree/master)  and source code for [fmi2slave.py](https://github.com/NTNU-IHB/PythonFMU/blob/master/pythonfmu/fmi2slave.py). It has to be `self.fmu_generator = FmuGenerator(instance_name=...)`. Other problem is `self.__init__()` in `def generate_fmu()`. If you need it then it also needs `instance_name=...` But I would rather put code from `FmuGenerator.__init__()` (it meas `for node in self.input_nodes: ....  subprocess(...)` in separated method and later execute this code in `FmuGenerator.__init__()` and in `def generate_fmu()`

Comment: Or I would put `for node in self.input_nodes: ....  subprocess(...)` only in `def generate_fmu()` and later in `FmuGenerator.__init__()` I would execute `self.generate_fmu(self.input_nodes)`